# Trying to populate with $push mongoose, but the result is null

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

i'm trying to populate using mongoose and $push but got null, and using postman it's says that the req.body is undefined. Can't see why(i'v added app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))) as a middleware. I want to send a message to the given user basically, but can't see what i'm doing wrong.

Here are the models:

User:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    messages: [
        
    ]
});
```

Message:

```
const messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    message: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

Here's the express route:

```
router.post('/send-message/:id', (req, res) => {
    return Message.create({ message: req.body.message })
        .then((result) => {
            return User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.authorId, {
                $push: { messages: result }
            }, {
                new: true
            }).exec((err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.send('error')
                } else {
                    res.send({ result })
                }
            })
        });
});
```

And here's a simple form:

```
<div>
    <form method="POST">
        <textarea class="text-area" name="message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Doesn't your `<form>` need an attribute `action="/send-message/<id>"`? Or how else does the submit button lead to a POST request? And where should the `req.params.authorId` come from? The parameter in the route is called `id`.

Comment: tried that, not working though :(

Comment: Ohh, yes, it was a typo in the route, it should have been authorId. Thanks, i was trying to fix that for hours, sometimes small mistakes makes big problems :)

Answer (score 0):

- Do this to your schema

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    ...
    messages: { 
        type: Array, 
        of: messageSchema
    },
});
```

- The form must have an action. Something like `action="/send-message/<id>"`
- The params don't match in your code. If this is a typo, ignore this, or else the `:id` in `/send-message/:id` can be accessed like this `req.params.id` and not `req.body.authorId`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using handlebars, so it's working even without `action="/"`. The problem was here :

```
<div class="contact-href">
    <a href="/send-message/{{authorId}}">Contact seller</a>
</div>
```

I specify it as that, so it wasn't working.